# Shorter Decimal Price

Tags: price, layered-navigation, navigation

If you install Magento and add Products and want to add a Price Slider you see The Price looks like that 0.2000 to 200.0000 on the left navigation bar. But in Europe you need only 2 digits after the decimal point so it should look like 0.20 to 200.00 how can I change that?

Answer (score 2):

look at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730180/format-price-in-the-current-locale-and-currency

you can use the same function in your slider template.

Example:

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($yourPrice, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the sneaky way via PHP's [number_format](https://www.php.net/number_format), i.e

echo "€ " . number_format($value, 2, ".", ",");

Answer (score 0):

Or just to make code bit more advanced, you can make your currency dynamic:

Try something like this:

```
$currency_symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency( $currency_code )->getSymbol();
$priceFormatted = number_format($product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',');
echo $currency_symbol.$priceFormatted;
```